# boost::asio and make_shared does not work?

Tags: boost-asio

I seem to be able to use boost::make_shared everywhere except with boost asio?

example: _ioService = boost::shared_ptr<io_service>(new io_service)

if I turn this into: _ioService = boost::make_shared<io_service>()

I get all kinds of errors?

Same problem if I take:
_acceptor  = boost::shared_ptr<tcp::acceptor>(new tcp::acceptor(*_ioService));

and turn it into this:
 _acceptor  = boost::make_shared<tcp::acceptor>(*_ioService);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `boost::asio::tcp::acceptor` takes a `boost::asio::io_service` by non-const reference you need to change:

```
_acceptor = boost::make_shared<tcp::acceptor>(*_ioService);
```

to:

```
_acceptor = boost::make_shared<tcp::acceptor>(boost::ref(*_ioService));
```